# Let $G$ be a non-abelian group, A normal abelian subgroup with index p prime, proof |A| congruent with |Z(G)| (center of G) mod p

Tags: abstract-algebra

I followed this steps:

$|A|\equiv |Z(G)| \pmod{p} \Leftrightarrow |A|-|Z(G)| = \dot{p}$

1. G non-abelian group $\rightarrow G \neq Z(G)$
2. |G:A| = p $\rightarrow \frac{|G|}{|A|} = p \Rightarrow |G|=p|A|$
3. $Z(G) \leq G$ and using Lagrange's theorem $\left|Z(G)\right|$ divides $\left| G \right| \ $  so $\exists \ c\in \mathbb{Z}$ : $|Z(G)|c = p|A| $

But im stuck and i'm not sure if i can prove it this way

EDIT: There was a mistake on the question, A must be abelian

Comment: "$|G|/|A| = p$"  only works if $G$ is finite. If you are assuming $G$ is finite, you need to say so; if you aren't, then you cannot assert this.

Comment: Well thats true, it's not specified if G is finite or not.

Comment: If $G$ is not finite, then "$|A|$ is congruent to $|Z(G)|$ modulo $p$" is a bit nonsensical. So if this problem is going to make sense, you'll have to assume $G$ is finite and say so explicitly. Not entirely clear what "$\dot{p}$" means, by the way. But I would advice thinking about the class equation.

Comment: Is it possible thinking of p lateral classes instead of $|G|/|A| = p$? so you can distinguish G finite and G infinite scenarios. $\dot{p}$ means a multiple of p

Comment: The problem is that if $G$ is infinite, and $A$ has finite index, then $A$ is infinite, so talking about $|A|$ being congruent modulo $p$ to $|Z(G)|$ would be nonsensical, regardless of whether $Z(G)$ is finite or not. Congruences are not defined for cardinals.

Comment: There was a mistake on the question, A must be abelian

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is the simplest route, but I answered the following two questions, and then concluded:

- Why is it impossible for an element of $Z(G)$ to be outside of $A$?
- Show that an element $x\in A$ either belongs to $Z(G)$, or $C_G(x)=A$, and in the latter case $x$ has exactly $p$ conjugates, all in $A$.

All the three assumptions, $G$ is non-abelian, $A$ is abelian, $A\lhd G$, are used in the proofs of the two bullet points.

---

Also test the claim (possibly also the outlined mechanism of arriving at it) with a small group, like the dihedral groups that have an obvious abelian normal subgroup of index two.

It feels natural to think that the class equation would come to the fore. But at least my solution only works with a subset of the conjugacy classes of $G$, namely those contained in $A$. Of course, the same underlying idea that the size of the conjugacy class is determined by the size of the centralizer is used here as well as when explaining the class equation.

Answer (score 1):

If $Z(G) \not\le A$, then there exists $g \in Z(G) \setminus A$.
Since $|G/A|$ is prime, it is generated by $gA$, and so every element of $G$ can be written as $g^kh$ for some $k$ with $0 \le k <p$, and $h \in A$. But such elements all commute with each other, so $G$ is abelian, contradiction.